# How to convert negative days into DateTime format in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a column which says DAYS_EMPLOYED which has negative integers. I need to convert them in Datetime format in Pandas. Please provide some inputs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are the number of days of employment from today then we can use `pd.DateOffset`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'employed_days' : [-9461,
                                     -16765,
                                     -19046]})



df['start_date'] = df['employed_days'].apply(lambda x : pd.Timestamp('today') - pd.DateOffset(days=abs(x)))

print(df)

   employed_days                 start_date
0          -9461 1994-07-24 16:35:51.025915
1         -16765 1974-07-25 16:35:51.025915
2         -19046 1968-04-26 16:35:51.025915
```

Comment: Thank you @Datanovic.

Comment: @KshitijKumar no problem - some tips, clean up your question and add in sample data (just copy & paste from your excel) don't use pictures and explain your question. If this question answered your query don't forget to accept it

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the input :)